# Does ramsey/uuid version 4 use "true" or pseudo-random numbers?

Tags: php, random, uuid

I'm using [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) in my project.
I'm creating new data entities with uuid4, which generates random UUIDs:

```php
Uuid::uuid4();
```

But I'm using this approach while bulk importing many thousands of data too. Now I'm worrying about the entropy pool of my system: does `uuid4` use a "true" random number which will deplete my entropy pool at some time? Or will it use pseudo-random numbers and I don't have to worry about?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it generates UUIDs from the `random_bytes()` function in PHP 7, or the polyfill from the paragonie/random_compat library in PHP 5. So its UUIDs are as random as the response from those functions. See the [RandomBytesGenerator class](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/blob/master/src/Generator/RandomBytesGenerator.php).

It depends what you're doing with the UUIDs as to whether that randomness is good enough.

Comment: Thank you! Since `random_bytes()` internally uses [`/dev/urandom`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) it never run out of systems entropy - which is exactly the answer I needed!